# Is there a better way to handle a "hover" event on touch devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

Is there a better way to handle a "hover" (this tapped, then effect active until something else is tapped) event on touch devices than using a global event handler to detect when the user taps something else?

---

For example, this code might work, but it relies on an event listener attached to the document body, so it's questionable performance-wise.

```
//note a namespace is used on the event to clear it without clearing all event listeners
$('myDiv').on('touchstart.temp', function () {
    //do stuff
    $('body').not(this).on('touchstart.temp', function () {
        //undo stuff
        $('body').not(this).off('touchstart.temp');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future you should be able to use the `touchenter` and `touchleave` events, which apply to specific elements.

```
$("myDiv").on("touchenter mouseover", function() {
    // do hover start code
}).on("touchleave mouseleave", function() {
    // do hover end code
});
```

But according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchenter), this is just a proposal which hasn't been implemented yet.

If you use jQuery Mobile, you can use the `vmouseover` and `vmouseleave` events, which simulate the mouse events on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript onmouseover and onmouseout events work just fine! :)

It won't work on mobile devices, but I believe you anticipated that.

Edit: I also noticed you included the JQuery tag. You could also use the JQuery hover method if it is to your liking.

i.e.

```
$('div').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }, function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/sofdz0s2/

As for hovering on all touch devices, it is not constant between all touch devices. Mine does not keep hovering after a tap. (I tried tapping on the div that changes and then on the green div, but it kept hovering after a tap.)

Edit 2:

As talked about in the comments, touchenter and touchleave are probably what you want.

I hope this helps!

Comment: No I need it to work on mobile, any touch device, thats the problem.

Comment: @Barmar Should I? I try to at least know how to do things in vanilla JS before deciding whether its worth adding more library functionality for.

Comment: @Viziionary I saw the jQuery tag, so I didn't think you were averse to using a library to simplify it. I guess the vanilla JS would be touchstart and touchend?

Comment: @Barmar well JQuery mobile would be a separate lib to add right? But if it's got a good solution I wouldnt be against it. I can at least look at how their source code does it.

Comment: Maybe this might be what you are looking for? http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml

Comment: Looks like `touchenter` and `touchleave` are what you want.

Comment: @Barmar exactly! Thanks. You should make that an answer. Unfortunately, it's early in introduction to the spec, so looks like Ill have to use that global selector for now.

Comment: Just to update new readers, the touchenter and touchleave events have been dropped from the W3C spec and as a result will likely not be implemented anywhere.

Should anyone reading this have any insight on why that decision was made, you're very welcome to share it.